# stored procedure returns varchar in LINQ

Tags: sql-server, linq-to-sql

I would like to know if in SQL is it possible to return a varchar value from a stored procedure, most of the examples I have seen the return value is an int

Example within a proc

```
declare @ErrorMessage varchar(255) if @TestFlag = 0 set @ErrorMessage = 'Test' 
return @ErrorMessage
```

calling on asp.net
Updated:

Error:
    **Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Development' to data type int.**

```
   using (DataContextDataContext dc = conn.GetContext())
{
    string serverName = ""
    var result = dc.spGetServerName(ref serverName);                    
    return result.ToString();

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't return anything but an int using the RETURN statement.
You'd need to use OUTPUT parameters instead. They are more flexible.

e.g.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ExampleSproc 
    @OutParam VARCHAR(10) OUTPUT
AS
SET @OutParam = 'Test'
...
GO
```

**Update:**
For an example on how to retrieve the output param, see [this article](http://mtaulty.com/CommunityServer/blogs/mike_taultys_blog/archive/2008/03/13/10236.aspx).

Comment: how do i call the storproc to get the output?

Comment: please see my updated question, the link you gave me is talk about int output what i am doing is returning string.

Comment: @Nisar Khan - it gives you the exact approach you need, it's just that in that example, the output parameter is an INTEGER. You just define your OUTPUT parameter as a VARCHAR, like my example, and tweak the .NET code to define the .NET variable as a string instead of an int like the example.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Please see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174998.aspx